# Right aligned custom list heading

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a custom list looks like ordinary html list where list heading is right aligned.

[image: html list]

```css
p { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; margin-left: 20px;">
  <p style="width: 20px; text-align: right;">i.</p>
  <div style="flex: 1;">
    <p>123</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; margin-left: 20px;">
  <p style="width: 20px; text-align: right;">ii.</p>
  <div style="flex: 1;">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work well when list heading is exceeding it's container width.

```html
<div style="display: flex; margin-left: 20px;">
  <p style="width: 20px; text-align: right;">iiiiiii.</p>
  <div style="flex: 1;">
    <p>123</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I make it text overflow to the left instead of right? I also tried using absolute position but no luck. Unfortunately I cannot use pseudo element or any html list elements, since I need to attach event listener on it.

Comment: Why can't you put event handlers on list elements?

Comment: Perhaps your intent is not clear and maybe more description is necessary but what you're showing would be rejected in code review for an enterprise application. There's probably a better way....

Comment: You are right, I can attach event on li, but default html element is hard to customize. like customize particular heading symbol, change color without changing list text content color etc. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: @Mengo, does the solution below work for your use case?

Comment: @Mengo see my updated example. The default element is still whatever display type you like as it's still subject to CSS box model (just like your divs and additional stuff in your example). What's shown is the cleanest most compliant example provided...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `text-align: right` in conjuction with `direction: rtl` to change the text direction.

Please see below:

```css
.text-direction {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
p{
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<div style=" margin-left: 60px;">
  <div style="display:flex">
  <p style="width: 20px; text-align: right;" class="text-direction">.ii</p>
  <div style="flex: 1;">
    <p>123456</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:flex">
  <p style="width: 20px; text-align: right;" class="text-direction">.iiii</p>
  <div style="flex: 1;">
    <p>123</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this should work, I have some issues in my working page where it goes to multi line when exceed container width, but that would be something else.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd want to keep it semantically correct. See below.

```css
ol.special-list {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ol.special-list li:after {
  counter-increment: item;
  content: " ." counter(item, upper-roman);
  font-weight: 600;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol class="special-list">
  <li>Blah 1</li>
  <li>Blah Blah 2</li>
  <li>Blah 3</li>
  <li>Blah Blah Blah Blah 4</li>
  <li>Blah 5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I updated my question, it's custom list, so no li, ol, ul allowed.

Comment: Why would a list element not be allowed?

Comment: We don't need to insert "." if we use default html list. list-style-type: lower-roman will do the work.